# GUI Layout Toolbox - Strange display with card panel object

Tags: matlab, user-interface

**Context**

Using the [GUI Layout toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) I have created an interface which basically is divided in two parts:

- A toolbar area where the user selects the way he want to see data
- A preview area to display data upon selected mode in the toolbar

For the preview area I used a [uietxras.CardPanel](http://cda.psych.uiuc.edu/matlab_programming_class_2012/guide/GUILayout_v1p10/GUILayout-v1p10/layoutHelp/Function%20reference1_2.html) object to switch between the view modes.

**Problem**

After some investigations, I discovered that if I display things in 3D (or 2D) in one of the preview card using `surf` (or `pcolor`) then it alters the display in the second card. If I display data in 1D only using `plot` commands I have not issue!

The issue I have when using pcolor/surf in one of the preview card:

- Titles and labels seem to overlay in `Preview 1`
- Axis borders are not displayed correctly in `preview 2`
- Legend borders (when displayed) are altered also

If I only use `plot` commands in both preview modes I have no issue at all and cards are switching nicely.

**Test case**

My real code is really long, I have thus reduced it to the minimum so you can reproduce the issue:

https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/54f3c1eba2293d0e5264#file-guilayoutbug-m

Simply run the code and check the checkbox "Do 3D plot in preview 1" to see the issue happening when switching between the two preview modes:

[image: GuiLayoutToolboxIssue]

**Notes**

- As far I know, I'm using latest version of the GUI Layout toolbox (1.17).
- I'm using R2013b for Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it, the issue has nothing to do with CardPanel themselves, it is linked to the renderer of the figure.

Trying simple code below:

```
figure(42);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(rand(1,12));
subplot(1,2,2);
peaks;
shading flat;
```

If the figure's renderer is set to 'OpenGL' (the default) ==> there are some glitches:

[image: OpenGLRenderer]

If the figure's renderer is set to 'zbuffer' ==> there is no glitch:

[image: zbufferRenderer]

**Setting the renderer to 'zbuffer' fixes the problem.**

NB: Maybe OpenGL rendering can be fixed by fine tuning graphic card acceleration settings, but I don't know ... I issued `opengl software` and `opengl hardware` commands in Matlab and `software` rendering is worst than `hardware` rendering on my machine.

**EDIT: Side notes**

Transparency effects are only available if the renderer is set to 'openGL'. It is thus not possible to visualize at the same time both 1D and transparent-3D data without glitches *(at least with hg version 1 in R2013b)*.

`HG2` has no issue:

[image]

Comment: Good stuff - zbuffer it is. Just a note for the future - in 14b, Handle Graphics 2 is coming out (at least, it's there in the 14b prerelease, and I sincerely hope MathWorks won't back it out). In HG2 most of the stuff about renderers should be less of an issue, as there is a whole new rendering pipeline for MATLAB graphics. The current version of GUI Layout Toolbox isn't supported in 14b/HG2, but the toolbox authors have stated that there will be a new version released to coincide with the full release of 14b. So hopefully this issue should go away then as well.

Comment: I tried HG2 with -hg switch on the command line in R2013b, it is very appealing. I hope also for a simpler way to design graphical interfaces rather than doing everything by code, but, hummm, that's challenging, so maybe not in next release... Thanks again for your advises and support.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue as well. I'm afraid I never quite worked out what the cause was exactly, and it didn't appear in a very consistent way. The issue seems to be that plots on non-selected cards are not hidden properly, and get overlaid just behind and around the edges of the plots on the selected card.

I would encourage you to raise the issue with the authors of GUI Layout Toolbox via the comments on the toolbox's page at MATLAB Central, as I do think it's a bug.

Nevertheless, the reason I never followed it up myself is that I found a fairly straightforward workaround, which may also work for you. Each time the selected card is changed, I ran a simple function that deleted all children of all cards, and then re-plotted whatever I wanted on the selected card. It seemed a bit annoying to have to do that, but it worked, and removed any of the display issues you've come across.

Comment: Good to read this. I will try your suggestions tomorrow morning and leave comment on toolbox's page in between. Thanks for your guidance :)

Comment: Ok ... I did clear axes children in invisible cards and it is working ... Investigating a little further for current case, setting visibility of `surf` object in the other card is sufficient (see [picture](http://hpics.li/8e62771))

Comment: Looking a little bit more to CardPanel code, invisible cards are just moved off-screen (comments say children are set invisible but it's not true, and it's maybe better not in order to not have to remind old status) ... Anyway, I tried changing visibility manually, it doesn't help ... So I definitely think the issue is linked to `hg` and that's it so far :(